# S3 and Signed URLs: Videos uploaded and retrieved won't play

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, dropzone.js

I've been knocking my head for hours trying to figure this out:

I'm using Dropzone.js to upload a video file to a private S3 bucket using a pre-signed URL. The goal is to later retrieve this file and play it using a `video` element.

If I don't set the `Content-Type` to the file type on the xhr request, S3 defaults it to `application/octet-stream`. The file uploads successfully and is in the expected location within the bucket.

When I try to retrieve this file using a signed URL and use it as a source for my `video`, it will not play - the element greys out with error. Additionally, if I access it in my browser, it downloads the file when I hit the URL rather than plays it back.

I did research and saw that it was downloading rather that streaming because I wasn't specifying it was a video, so I tried to do that.

If I do set the `Content-Type` to `'video/mp4'` and retrieve it using a signed URL, it will neither play in the video element nor will it play OR download in the browser. It seems like this makes the file unusable for some reason.

I've verified that my retrieving and playing code work correctly by using files that were manually uploaded to S3 rather than uploading via Dropzone. Something is going wrong in the upload process, whether it's with Dropzone or S3, and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I never found a solution to this - something was being corrupted when the file was passing between Dropzone and S3 due to the fact that Dropzone submits FormData I believe. I ended up using a straight XHR request and uploading the file successfully without Dropzone.